# Building a statement

Tags: google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

SOLVED!!!!!!!

I have the following sheet that I'm working with:

[image: Data Sample]

I'm looking to build a transaction details statement like this one:

[image: Output Required]

Now comes the fun part - The Query

I have tried to merge two Google queries, but I am having a problem with the headers that come up because of the empty column that I need to have on each query.

This is what I have so far:

```
={query({Sheet3$A$1:$F},"Select Col1, Col3,' ', Col6 where Col2= '"&B1&"'",1);query({Sheet3!$A$2:$F},"Select Col1, ' ', Col5, Col6 where Col4= '"&B1&"'",0)}
```

Problems:

1. I can tweak it to get the headers I want in query 1, but query 2 gets a weird header (" "()  ) Like this one - because of the empty column.
2. The two queries appear together, but I cannot merge them successfully i.e. in order of time logs.

The solution was the following query:

=sort({query({Sheet3!$A$1:$F},"Select Col1, Col3,' ', Col6 where Col2= '"&B1&"' label ' ' '' ",0);query({Sheet3!$A$2:$F},"Select Col1, ' ', Col5, Col6 where Col4= '"&B1&"' label ' ' ''",0)},1,TRUE)

This removed all headers and also put the data together without the annoying empty row in the middle. ALSO.. adding sort(full query,1,TRUE) allowed me to sort the records by the 1st column which achieved the desired result.

Lastly - i added the headers manually which was absolutely fine as these will never change or require any updates.

THANK YOU ALL!!!!

Comment: Hi! Could you please share a sample of your sheet (without any senstive data) so that we can test and visualise clearly what you are aiming to do? Thanks !

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Thanks for answering. This is literrally the sheet i want to work with Would you just like me to put this in a google sheet and share it?

Comment: Here's a link : I've ttried to incorporate the answer given below but it still leaves an empty line. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQCxEtVOHpJqiJplt7fmhAR74f-hv01XXqoPOEMx_1U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default QUERY includes headers. In order to prevent that QUERY add headers for your second QUERY you could use the `label` clause to replace the default label for the  `' '` column by and empty string `label ' ' ''`

The resulting second QUERY looks like this:

`query({Sheet3!$A$2:$F},"Select Col1, ' ', Col5, Col6 where Col4= '"&B1&"' label ' ' ''",0)`

Comment: Thank you, I've added a comment with the sheet link - and incorporated your answer. I tried this earlier many times but it always left an empty line. Not sure how to remove that.

Comment: My final step in this is to sort the results after having them as one group (without the empty line) - by the timedate column. Thank you for answering